# Optimize SQLite query with ordering by computed column?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using sqlite query to to find a motor with best set of calibration values using a certain formula. In the original query I am ordering the computed column (to select top 1), this I believe slows down my query the most.

I am trying to make this query as fast as possible. Currently execution time is about 0.300 seconds, and I was able to reduce it to 0.150 seconds by restricting table with `Volume BETWEEN (0.9*1.7006359100341797) AND (1.1*1.7006359100341797)` and by using tempTable to do the sorting of computed table (`BestMotor`).

What else can I do to improve this more? MotorTable table has ~30,000 rows. Number of distinct MotorVendors is about 55.

Here is my original query:
I am trying to find CalX and CalY that are closest to specified volume for each distinct MotorVendor.

```
SELECT T.MotorVendor, ((1/(CalX)+1/(CalY))) AS BestMotor FROM (
SELECT MotorVendor,
       (SELECT CalX
        FROM MotorTable AS T2
        WHERE MotorType = 'text' and T2.MotorVendor = Tools.MotorVendor
        ORDER BY abs(Volume - 1.7006359100341797)
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS CalX,
       (SELECT CalY
        FROM MotorTable AS T2
        WHERE MotorType = 'text' and T2.MotorVendor = Tools.MotorVendor
        ORDER BY abs(Volume - 1.7006359100341797)
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS CalY
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MotorVendor,
      FROM MotorTable) AS Tools) AS T
      WHERE T.CalX != '' AND T.CalY != ''
      ORDER BY BestMotor DESC
      LIMIT 1;
```

And here is query using tempTable to order the computed column (with index on that computed column in tempTable):

```
DELETE FROM TempTable;
INSERT INTO TempTable SELECT T.MotorVendor, ((1/(CalX)+1/(CalY))) AS BestMotor FROM (
SELECT MotorVendor,
       (SELECT CalX
        FROM MotorTable AS T2
        WHERE MotorType = 'text' and T2.MotorVendor = Tools.MotorVendor AND Volume BETWEEN (0.9*1.7006359100341797) AND (1.1*1.7006359100341797)
        ORDER BY abs(Volume - 1.7006359100341797)
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS CalX,
       (SELECT CalX
        FROM MotorTable AS T2
        WHERE MotorType = 'text' and T2.MotorVendor = Tools.MotorVendor AND Volume BETWEEN (0.9*1.7006359100341797) AND (1.1*1.7006359100341797)
        ORDER BY abs(Volume - 1.7006359100341797)
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS CalX
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MotorVendor,
      FROM MotorTable) AS Tools) AS T
      WHERE T.CalX != '' AND T.CalY != ''
      ORDER BY BestMotor DESC
      LIMIT 1;
SELECT MotorVendor, BestMotor FROM TempTable ORDER BY BestMotor DESC LIMIT 1;
```

UPDATE...

I was able to reduce it to 0.05 seconds...
I have created a table to store all distinct MotorVendor and change main query to this:

```
SELECT T.MotorVendor FROM (
SELECT MotorVendor,
       (SELECT CalX
        FROM MotorTable AS T2
        WHERE MotorType = 'text' and T2.MotorVendor = Tools.MotorVendor AND Volume BETWEEN (0.9*1.7006359100341797) AND (1.1*1.7006359100341797)
        ORDER BY abs(Volume - 1.7006359100341797)
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS CalX,
       (SELECT CalY
        FROM MotorTable AS T3
        WHERE MotorType = 'text' and T3.MotorVendor = Tools.MotorVendor AND Volume BETWEEN (0.9*1.7006359100341797) AND (1.1*1.7006359100341797)
        ORDER BY abs(Volume - 1.7006359100341797)
        LIMIT 1
        ) AS CalY       
FROM TempMotorVendorTable AS Tools) AS T
      ORDER BY ((1/(CalX)+1/(CalY))) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Here are schemas of two tables and indexes I have created.

```
CREATE TABLE MotorTable (
    CalY    real,
    CalX    real,
    Volume  real,
    MotorType   text,
    MotorVendor text
);
CREATE TABLE TempMotorVendorTable (
    MotorVendor TEXT
);
CREATE INDEX `MotorVendorIndex` ON MotorTable (`MotorVendor` ASC)
CREATE INDEX VolumeIndex ON MotorTable (Volume DESC)
```

Output of EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN

```
"0" "0" "0" "SCAN TABLE TempMotorVendorTable AS Tools"
"0" "1" "1" "SEARCH TABLE MotorTable USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (MotorVendor=?)"
"0" "0" "0" "EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 1"
"1" "0" "0" "SEARCH TABLE MotorTable AS T2 USING INDEX CompToolIndex (MotorVendor=?)"
"1" "0" "0" "USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY"
"0" "0" "0" "EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 2"
"2" "0" "0" "SEARCH TABLE MotorTable AS T3 USING INDEX CompToolIndex (MotorVendor=?)"
"2" "0" "0" "USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY"
"0" "0" "0" "USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY"
```

Comment: Show the database schema and the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).

Comment: Just updated my question with more detail for schema and output of `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`

Comment: What is `historyCR`?

Comment: Sorry. It's `MotorTable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORDER BY abs(Volume - 1.234)` cannot be optimized with an index.
(Not even in the next version of SQLite, which will have expression indexes, because the `1.234` value is not constant.)

However, you don't actually want to order *all* rows, you just want the one nearest row.
This can be done with a different query, which searches for the first row *below* that value and the first row *above* that value (these searches and sortings on `Volume` can use an index). Then take the nearest of these two rows (sorting only two rows is fast):

```sql
(SELECT CalX
 FROM (SELECT CalX, diff
       FROM (-- get the largest value at or below 1.234
             SELECT CalX, abs(Volume - 1.234) AS diff
             FROM MotorTable AS T2
             WHERE MotorType = 'text'
               AND MotorVendor = Tools.MotorVendor 
               AND Volume <= 1.234
             ORDER BY Volume DESC
             LIMIT 1)
       UNION ALL
       SELECT CalX, diff
       FROM (-- get the smallest value above 1.234
             SELECT CalX, abs(Volume - 1.234) AS diff
             FROM MotorTable AS T2
             WHERE MotorType = 'text'
               AND MotorVendor = Tools.MotorVendor 
               AND Volume > 1.234
             ORDER BY Volume ASC
             LIMIT 1)
       ORDER BY diff
       LIMIT 1)
)
```

To make the searches in `MotorTable` efficient, you need a single index on all three columns, and the inequality comparison must be on the last one:

```sql
CREATE INDEX xxx ON MotorTable(MotorType, MotorVendor, Volume);
```

Comment: Just adding proper index made it execute in just 0.004 seconds. I will try to change the query too. Thanks.